# why new FileWriter(...) return /data/data/com.myapp.client/files/myfile.json (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, filewriter, android-file

Why when I do :

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/data/data/com.myapp.client/files/myfile.json", true/*append*/);
```

on some very few device (one most of them it's work well) I receive : `/data/data/com.myapp.client/files/myfile.json (No such file or directory)`. How can I avoid this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't hardcode the path, use `Context.getFilesDir` instead

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "file.json")
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) for reference.